# Uploading a package to melpa

Tags: package-repositories

I like `sqlplus` package on emacs.
It works perfect when I use oracle dbms, however,
my company uses `Tibero`, which is not available on melpa repository.

I would like to write a melpa package for this specific db.
What procedures should I follow if I want to upload the package on melpa   repository?
Is there a good tutorial for this?

Comment: Melpa is on github, where you will find instructions posted in the readme. If you have particular questions about something after reading that, ask a specific question here.